# How to make a variable global for requires

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var tester = require('./../_common/tester');
var testCases = require('./test-cases');
var config = require('./config.js');


var data = {
  nightmare: Nightmare(config.nightmare),
  config: config,
  testCases: testCases,
  tester: tester
};
```

This data contains mainly configuration variables and functions.

Then  I have the following set of functions which require all those configurations and functions:

```
  var resultsPromise = pipeline([
    commonFunctions.accessURL(data),
    commonFunctions.loginToWebsite1(data),
    commonFunctions.loginToWebsite2(data),
    commonFunctions.loginToWebsite3(data),
    commonFunctions.accessURL2(data),
  ])
  .then(() => commonFunctions.success(nightmare))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Is passing data as I do correct? Is there any other way of making the variable global for those functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fine but if you want to use this configuration in many file then you can make any variable or object global with a global keyword

```
global.data = {}
```

and data object is accessible anywhere

Comment: How should I access it from other files?

Comment: you can write "global.data" or just "data" its accessible anywhere. for example if you define var someData = 0; in file then it can be accessible with someData in whole file. Just like that you can access it anywhere in any file with just writing data.

Answer (score 0):

```
global.Nightmare = require('nightmare');
```

use this in your dependencies file